# Downcasting and copying a const object

Tags: c++, qt, sigabrt, dynamic-cast, descendant

My method receives an object as a parameter and it must be accepted as a base type (though it is sent as a Derived type).  I want to make a copy of this object AND down cast it to a derived type, so that I can call a method of the derived type (which modifies properties of the derived object).

I've been messing with variations of dynamic_cast, but can't make the compiler happy, OR, it compiles and I get a sigABRT on the dynamic_cast line (as per below):

```
void mymethod(Base message) {
    if (message.messageType() == "D") {
        Derived& derivedMessage = dynamic_cast<Derived&>(message);
        Derived derivedCopy = derivedMessage;
        derivedCopy.derMethod();
```

In case it matters, mymethod is a Qt SLOT, which receives the signal across threads.  I don't think one can (or at least safely) pass a pointer to an object across threads, which is why I'm passing by value.

Comment: There is probably a typo with the unterminated string in  `if (message.messageType() == "D) {`

Comment: I simplified the question to get rid of 'const'.  The problem seems to be more about downcasting

Comment: @George `dynamic_cast<Derived&>(message);` doesn't automatically _have_ UB. It depends on what's known about `message". There's also no object slicing there unless the types are _non_-virtual (which seems unlikely).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> void mymethod(const Base message)
> ```

If you pass a parameter of type `Base`, then the type of the object is `Base` and not something else - i.e. it will never be an object of a derived type.

If you want to have runtime polymorphism, then you need to use indirection. Typical solution is to pass a *reference* to a base class subobject:

```
void mymethod(const Base& message)
```

The referred base can be a subobject within any derived class.

Comment: Note that message is a copy of the object passed to mymethod() and not the original object. Thus all the derived members are not copied. Unless you pass a pointer or a reference.

Comment: @jens - I call mymethod was an object of type Derived.  Are you saying that when mymethod makes a copy of the 'message' parameter it is stripped of all Derived stuff, and has now become a Base object?  (So it cannot be downcast?)  So one can never downcast an object if it has been received by value?

Comment: @eerorika - I call mymethod with an object of type Derived.  I can't use indirection because this is a Qt slot (added to question), and object is passed using signal/slot mechanism of Qt.  (Which doesn't allow passing references across threads - I don't think)

Comment: Yes - message is stripped of all derived aspects.

Comment: Ok that explains the cause of the sigabrt.  Can you suggest a way to do this (given the Qt signal/slot constraint)? i.e. passed object of type Derived, receive object of type Base.  Passing pointer to object across threads seems dangerous since obj may be destroyed by caller shortly after signal is sent.

Comment: And a note on Qt and Threads: I vaguely remember that Qt in case of signals with const-reference parameters calls the copy constructor for making a temporary object from the one passed into the signal (otherwise a signalled stack object might get deleted before it is delivered to the receiving thread).

Comment: @TSG `I can't use indirection` If that's true, then you cannot have polymorphism. Indirection is a precondition to achieve polymorphism. If you cannot have a reference, then you could pass a pointer to the base subobject instead, or a reference wrapper. Those can be passed by value, and provide the indirection that you need.